# Prevent "Enter" key action react-native

Tags: react-native

There is no way to prevent a TextInput field from updating the text given a key input. For instance, even if I want to reserve "Enter" for a special purpose in a multiline textinput, when I press it the component first forces the on screen text to perform an "Enter" action, namely by adding `\n` to the input value. But I don't want this to happen. I just want to listen for an "Enter" event while suppressing the "Enter" action similar to `onKeyDown.preventDefault()` in javascript for html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onSubtmitEditing` on your `TextInput` and add `returnKeyType='go'` (iOs and Android).

```
<TextInput
    returnKeyType='go'
    blurOnSubmit={true}
    onSubmitEditing={()=>this.useYourDataHereBeforeSending()} />
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onsubmitediting