# How to make second line in text Input while entering text in react native?

Tags: react-native, onchange, textinput

i want second line if i entered more then 10 char in textInput. I have done changing text's font size if more then 5 char entered. that is works fine.

But if i enter more then 11 char it should comes down in second line

please help me to clear this

here is my code ...

```
_onChangeText(text) {
     this.setState({ fontSize: (text.lenght > 6 ? 40 : 80) });
 }

 render() {
return (
  // Giving an array of objects to style property can help                                                    
 you to define a default value
      <TextInput 
          onChangeText={this._onChangeText.bind(this)}
          style={[ {fontSize: 80}, {fontSize: this.state.fontSize} ]}
     />
   )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this,

```
state = {
  fontSize: 80,
  inputValue: ''
}

onChangeText(event) {
  this.setState({
    fontSize: event.nativeEvent.text.length > 6 ? 40 : 80,
    inputValue: event.nativeEvent.text
  });
}

render() {
return (
  < TextInput
    multiline
    onChange={(event) =>
      this.onChangeText(event)
    }
    onContentSizeChange={(event) => {
      this.setState({ height: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height })
    }}
    value={this.state.inputValue}
    style={{ fontSize: this.state.fontSize, height: Math.max(35, 
    this.state.height) }}
  />
    )
  }
}
```

set multiline and handle the height of your textinput

Comment: should i add one more method of this onChangeText(event){ } ? @Ganesh Cauda

Comment: You can use external method like i did on the example, or you can directly inject everything inside that method on the onChange

Comment: but if add multiline={true} after typed the keyboard not getting resigned

Comment: If you assign multiline, its not necessary to put true statement, it is true by default

Comment: yeah thats okay but if input empty then multiline should not work... in iphone keyboard if i press return key while not entering text its coming down... that should not happen

Comment: if input is empty then keyboard enter next line should not work@Ganesh Cauda

Comment: you can disable the enter button if the text is empty, here is the reference how to disable the enter : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537486/prevent-enter-key-action-react-native

Answer (score 9):

Set `multiline` prop to `true`. No check is required for the no. of characters. It automatically takes care of the no. of characters it can accomodate according to the width. Works completely fine for me -> [image]

If you have a specific requirement of 10 characters then set the value of `multiline` as true as soon as the length of the characters reaches 10

Docs available [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#multiline)

Answer (score 3):

Use `multiline` (boolean) property to detect when you need to show multiple lines.

```
_onChangeText(text) {
  const areCharsExceeded = text.length > 10;

  this.setState({ areCharsExceeded });
}

 <TextInput
  multiline={this.state.areCharsExceeded}
  onChangeText={this._onChangeText.bind(this)}
/>
```

Comment: i have a state inside this _onChageText(text) function ?? @zvona

Comment: zvona ping me on chat if you are free @zvona

Answer (score 0):

```
<! -- use multiline to able the effect, multilive is a boolean and by default is false -->

<TextInput
    placeholder="broke line"
    multiline
/>

<! -- if you set a fixed height then multiline will not work, to fix this issue use min-height instead of height-->
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).